# In Jenkins, How to run a Python script that calls AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cli

I'm trying to configure a Jenkins build to run a Python script that makes use of the AWS CLI.

The script runs without issue when run from the command line
`cd /home/pi python3 AmzTools/Run_Notifications.py`

However, when I try running the same commands in a Jenkins build I get the following:

```
22:06:19 Started by user Paul Anderson
22:06:19 Running as SYSTEM
22:06:19 Building in workspace /home/pi
22:06:19 [pi] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins10138978078974220181.sh
22:06:19 + BUILD_USER=pi
22:06:19 + python3 AmzTools/Run_Notifications.py
22:06:22 UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION - add handing for this
22:06:22 Traceback (most recent call last):
22:06:22   File "/home/pi/AmzTools/AWS/Notifications.py", line 72, in get_offer_notifications
22:06:22     sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
22:06:22   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 92, in resource
22:06:22     return _get_default_session().resource(*args, **kwargs)
22:06:22   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 389, in resource
22:06:22     aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
22:06:22   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
22:06:22     aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
22:06:22   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 861, in create_client
22:06:22     client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
22:06:22   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 76, in create_client
22:06:22     verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
22:06:22   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 285, in _get_client_args
22:06:22     verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
22:06:22   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/botocore/args.py", line 45, in get_client_args
22:06:22     endpoint_url, is_secure, scoped_config)
22:06:22   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/botocore/args.py", line 111, in compute_client_args
22:06:22     service_name, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure)
22:06:22   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 358, in resolve
22:06:22     service_name, region_name)
22:06:22   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 122, in construct_endpoint
22:06:22     partition, service_name, region_name)
22:06:22   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 135, in _endpoint_for_partition
22:06:22     raise NoRegionError()
**22:06:22 botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.**
22:06:38 Terminated
22:06:38 Build was aborted
22:06:38 Aborted by Paul Anderson
22:06:38 Finished: ABORTED
```

My first thought was that AWS wasn't configured correctly, so I tried configuring it for SUDO and jenkins users, but I'm still getting the same error.

How can I configure the Jenkins build so it either runs as my default user (`pi` in this case), or somehow make this work in another way?

Comment: Can you show the command that you run with aws cli? You need to specify region in it.

Comment: @Marcin - it's a call to SQS via the Boto3 module in Python - sqs = boto3.resource('sqs').  It works as expected when I'm signed in as myself (pi i this case), but whatever user it runs under in Jenkins doesn't work

Comment: Because region in the aws cli command is missing. `You must specify a region` When you run it yourself, region is taken from your profile. Without that, region is unknown. You can try using env variables to specify region.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, I'm not sure how to specify a region at runtime, but found I hadn't configured it correctly in the jenkins area, despite thinking I had previously done so

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out where I was going wrong, so posting an answer in case anyone else has the same issue.

It turned out that I hadn't logged into the Jenkins user when I was configuring AWS, so when the build called AWS CLI from as Jenkins user it couldn't see the credentials.  I simply had to log in as jenkins and set my AWS configuration.

I tried `su - jenkins`, but it was asking for a password, which isn't set by default.

I set a password - `sudo passwd jenkins`

Logged in as jenkins user - `su - jenkins`

Then configured AWS CLI with my credentials `aws configure`

Thanks to @marcin for reminding me to keep looking for the region.